# Rust: Holding a Filter inside a struct

Tags: rust, rust-0.11

I'm attemping to make a struct with a `Filter` iterator inside:

```
struct Foo {
    inner_iter: Filter<...>,
}
```

I'm then going to make Foo an Iterator itself, which will use the Filter internally.

The problem is, I can't seem to figure out what goes in between the braces after `Filter`. The docs say Filter is the following:

```
pub struct Filter<'a, A, T> {
    // some fields omitted
}
```

`A` seems to be my return type. What are `'a` and `T`? Nothing I attempt makes it compile.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can see [here](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Filter.html) that `Filter` implements `Iterator` trait in the following way:

```
impl<'a, A, T: Iterator<A>> Iterator<A> for Filter<'a, A, T>
```

This means that yes, `A` is its element type, and `T` is *underlying iterator* type. If you look into `Filter` definition, you will also find that `'a` is lifetime of environment of predicate closure.

If you want to make your own wrapper for the `Filter`, it could look like this:

```
struct CustomWrapper<'a, A, T> {
    inner_iter: Filter<'a, A, T>
}
```

You need to pass through all parameters to `Filter`. Of course, if you're working with some specific element type, you can specify it instead of using type parameter:

```
struct CustomWrapper<'a, T> {
    inner_iter: Filter<'a, int, T>
}
```

However, you still need to pass `'a` and `T` because they are likely to be arbitrary.

Comment: As it happens, I am working with `int`s. My `Foo` struct won't be polymorphic. Since I'm dealing with `int`s and ONLY `int`s internally, what should I make 'a and T?

Comment: You should leave them as they are and pass them around as generic parameters, if you're deriving `Filter` from some iterator which is passed to your API by its user. They have to be generic because the user may pass *any* iterator, and its type has to be present in `Filter` signature.

Comment: I don't need to be general as I'm just making a toy program for my own purposes. I'm just trying to figure out _what values of 'a and T_ could be acceptable.

Comment: You can't specify any custom value for `'a`, it is provided by the compiler automatically when you call `filter()` and pass a closure to it. You can't omit it in your structure definition. As for `T`, you can use some concrete iterator structure here, for example, [this](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Items.html) one, but it will limit you to using only that specific iterator with your structure. For example, you will be able to use `some_vec.iter()` but not `some_vec.move_iter()` as they return different iterators.